# trouble with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

```
// following code works fine n open notepad...   
class demo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("notepad");
    pb.start();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.print(e);}
}
}
 //however the above code throws an exception when any other system program is executed
class demo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("calculator");
    pb.start();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.print(e);}
}
}
```

the above program throws following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Calculator": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the full path to the executable (including the directories and the .exe extension).

Should actually be apparent from the error message you got :-)

(The reason `"notepad"` worked indicates that it will search `%PATH%` and try to append `.exe` if necessary. This leads me to believe that `"calc"` may also work :-)